# Is using the Firebase Auth user.uid as part of the url a bad practice?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The reason behind using the user.uid as part of the url is to share some assets related to each user. Does using the user.uid expose the app to exploits or impersonification from malicious users? What other options do I have to uniquely identify users assets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user uid as part of the URL is ok. You should never trust the uid when checking if a user is authenticated. The right way is to check the ID token and verifying. You can use the Firebase Admin SDKs to do so. Make sure you send the ID token along the request to your server.

Comment: Agree, for authentication verification I rely in the `onAuthStateChanged` observer.